# Javascript Replace Doesn't Work in Google.com

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have an extension that replaces text on the page. It works great in every site expcept for google. On the initial page load it doesn't work. When I refresh the page, sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't. If I click a link from google and then go back it loads fine. It does work fine in every other page (at least every page I've tested so far).

Does anyone know why the below code would cause this problem and know how to fix it? This is taken from my background.js. I have to make sure the text, not the text html tags is replaced.

```
$.fn.replaceText = function (search, replace, text_only) {
    return this.each(function () {
        var node = this.firstChild,
            val,
            new_val,
            remove = [];
        if (node) {
            do {
                if (node.nodeType === 3) {
                    val = node.nodeValue;
                    new_val = val.replace(search, replace);
                    if (new_val !== val) {
                        if (!text_only && /</.test(new_val)) {
                            $(node).before(new_val);
                            remove.push(node);
                        } else {
                            node.nodeValue = new_val;
                        }
                    }
                }
            } while (node = node.nextSibling);
        }
        remove.length && $(remove).remove();
    });
};

chrome.storage.local.get(function (cfg) {
    //get replacedWord array
    if (typeof (cfg["replacedWord"]) !== 'undefined' && cfg["replacedWord"] instanceof Array) {
        var myWords = cfg["replacedWord"];
        var newWords = cfg["newWords"];

        for (var j = 0; j < myWords.length; ++j) {
            var thisWord = new RegExp(myWords[j], "i");
            $("body *").replaceText(thisWord, '<abbr title="Test Hover"><font color="red">' + newWords[j] + '</font></abbr>');
        } //end for loop
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm guessing that this is probably because your script runs as soon as the page loads, and google loads an empty page then includes the content. You would have to somehow monitor changes to the pages content.

Comment: Interesting! I was trying to figure out why this would be! Is there a way a to delay it from background.js for a few seconds? Would that be a good idea?

Comment: [`window.setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) but this won't account if you happen to have a slow connection.

Comment: Intermittent issues in javascript are almost always async related. If it works sometimes and not others it's likely due to the order in which the events are executed. Not sure how you can get a load ready statement from an external page, but if nothing else a delay timer could let you know that it is indeed an async issue. delay your activity for 5000 milisecs and see if it then works and you'll have your answer.

Comment: So I'm still having an issue with this and after playing with timer and other things believe I've found the problem. Though I check for node.nodetype of 3, this script is replacing the word when in the metatag and a few javascript functions which is why the page won't load. How is it that this can happen when the nodetype is 3??